# Diagonal scrolling when both X and Y scrollbars are available

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a magic trackpad (a touchpad) and one thing I have noticed is that applications such as Adobe Photoshop will let me scroll diagonally (both X and Y axis at the same time).

I never thought about using that same functionality in my browser, as I didn't have any use case for it. Until now. I'm working on a project which has a "canvas" (a drawing area) that is bigger than the visible area of the browser.

I have scrolling bars (`overflow: auto;`), but moving around the canvas just doesn't feel as "good" (in terms of UX) as with Photoshop. That's because I can't scroll both axes at the same time.

Eg, if I'm at the top left corner of the canvas and I want to go to the bottom right corner, in Photoshop I just touch-drag diagonally two fingers on my touchpad, but in Chrome/Safari/Firefox I first have to scroll down and then scroll right.

Visual example: https://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/XWpPJNj  (the left area shows the entire canvas, the right one is what the user sees. Try to scroll in the right area until you see the red square.)

Is there any way I can implement diagonal scrolling?

Comment: Rough idea of how to do this... on mousedown, record your mouse coords, on mouseup record your mouse coords, place the elements scrollTo coords on mousedown to the coords recorded for mouseup.  Or for mobile touchstart, touchend...

Comment: @dalelandry I was talking about "natural" scrolling, not dragging. Note that I don't need to "drag" the canvas when I'm using Photoshop.

Comment: Was it always this way?  I have a large table in an overflow container and I could've sworn at one point I could pan around on the trackpad diagonally.  Now it's very unnaturally feeling where I have to dance between both axis.  It could just be me remembering wrong, however.